How to execute this time-stamped auto-backup function every N minutes?
This code will create a time-stamped backup of the current Notebook. How can I execute it every 5 minutes?
task = {
   sec = 
    ToString@NumberForm[AbsoluteTime[], 10, 
      ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-10, 10}];
   originalFile = NotebookFileName[];
   name = FileNameTake[originalFile, -1];
   fileName = StringSplit[name, "."][[1]];
   fname = StringJoin[{fileName, "-", sec, "nb"}];
   pathName = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, fname}];
   Export[File[pathName], EvaluationNotebook[]];
  };

I've been trying to use SessionSubmit, ScheduledTask & TaskResume but keep getting a message:
TaskResume::taskid: A string or a TaskObject is expected instead of $Failed.



I guess, in the new task session, you can not use the expected NotebookName[] existing in the caller session.

You need to run the below code in a named notebook file.


(*Capture the notebook's file name before the scheduled task*)
originalFile = NotebookFileName[];

(*Define the backup function with originalFile as a parameter*)
backupNotebook[originalFile_] := 
  Module[{sec, name, fileName, fname, pathName}, 
   sec = ToString@
     NumberForm[AbsoluteTime[], 10, 
      ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-10, 10}];
   Print["originalFile=", originalFile];
   name = FileNameTake[originalFile, -1];
   Print["name=", name];
   fileName = StringSplit[name, "."][[1]];
   fname = StringJoin[{fileName, "-", sec, ".nb"}];
   pathName = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, fname}];
   Print["pathName=", pathName];
   Export[File[pathName], EvaluationNotebook[]];];

(*Create and start the scheduled task, passing originalFile*)
{period, count} = {3, 4};
task = SessionSubmit[
  ScheduledTask[backupNotebook[originalFile], {period, count}]]

(*Optional:Control the task*)
TaskExecute[task];
(*TaskResume[task];*)
(*TaskAbort[task];*)
(*TaskRemove[task];*)


Thanks, that completes the functionality I immediately need.
